# How can I access numerical values of variables calculated with Solve?

Tags: list-manipulation, equation-solving

I am trying to calculate some thermodynamical cycles so I often use lists with equations. Here's a simple example:

```
list1 = {
     x + 2 y == z,
     z - 2 x == 3z,
     y - z == 5 x}

Solve[list1,{x,y,z}]
```

> ```
> {{x -> 0, y -> 0, z -> 0}}
> ```

The problem appears when I want to use the calculated values of `x,y,z` later on to calculate some other parameters. *Mathematica* every time keeps returning `x,y or z` instead of its numerical value. Is that because the result of `Solve` is a nested list? Anyway, what should I do to have an access to these values?

Comment: Thanks a lot, I found a solution there. Next time I'll dig deeper.

Comment: Welcome to the site at any rate!